# Is it possible to update a running container's mount information?

Tags: kubernetes

In my kubernetes cluster , I ran a harbor with glusterfs as a storage backend .

but sometimes glusterfs will restart automatically, but harbor pod cannot be notified if glusterfs recovers .

I just want to know if it possible to recover harbor without deleting harbor's pod.

**1, can I run `mount -a` or `mount -o remount` for harbor pod in host environment?**

**2, does kubernetes offer any way to solve this? CSI? PV?**

thanks for any advice

---

**UPDATE**

I found someone tried to mount volume to a running container:
https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/issues/697 
https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/01/13/docker-mount-dynamic-volumes/

But these article seem very old, they can work for real block device , but can not work on nas like  glusterfs.

Comment: Deleting the pod is totally routine; commands like `kubectl rollout restart deployment` can do it for you, and sometimes the cluster will do it on its own.  If deleting the pod fixes the problem, that seems like it'll be much easier than trying to do anything manually to the broken pod.

Comment: yeah, I will try to delete thaht pod by hand if I know , but sometimes glusterfs is very senstive to network drop or some programe bug.  I want the recovery become automatically for the pods which are using glusterfs or other NAS filesystem . Maybe automatically ` rollout  ` is a choice .

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to recover the harbor without deleting the harbor's pod but by using/running ‘mount - a’ or ‘mount - o’  is not a good idea as it may cause data corruption.

The best option is to use [Persistent Volumes(PV) and Persistent Claims(PVC)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) to manage the storage of the Harbour. Kubernetes will reschedule a Pod to another node where GlusterFS is available and the PVC will be attached to the new PV.

Or you can use [Kubernetes CSI official document by Saad Ali](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/01/15/container-storage-interface-ga/) but the above method of using PV & PVC is the best and recommended approach.